# Custom Katakana Input

Tags: c#, ime, monomac

I've have a 100% custom desktop app created in C# that is now sold worldwide.

Some of my customers have complained that it doesn't support different IMEs, Input Method editors, e.g. you set your input to Japanese katakana or something similar, then type of few characters and it creates a Japanese Unicode character.

Does anybody know where to start with this? I can't figure out where or how to detect this kind of input or even how to do the conversion. E.g. given an input 'k' then 'a' you get カ.

I need to code this on Windows (using Winforms) and Mac (using Monomac or Cocoa). Either would be a helpful start.

Comment: What specific problem are you having? With IMEs, you will get multiple keystrokes before the user selects the final one, so if you have any code in KeyDown or KeyPress events, that may be causing the problem. Have you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392606/c-sharp-and-ime-getting-the-current-input-text

Comment: Normally you don't need to take care of this as the IME would automatically do all of this. So you would just install the IME (see https://www.coscom.co.jp/learnjapanese801/install_ime.html if you want to try use an IME yourself) and enable IME mode and everything should work out of the box. However, if you handle keyboard events yourself and do some special stuff the IME may interfere with your processing. Maybe these are the reported errors.